# Save input from textfield and send to server [objective c]

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services

I am creating an app which takes the input from a textfield on the screen - and sends it to my php server. But I am new to programming and I don't know how to do. I followed some guides at apple development and learned how to create the textfield, modify it and create a delegate. But from here I don't know what to do. As soon as someone hits the "Send" button the keyboard should go down and the message should be sent to my server. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you written the server side portion? If so, how does it expect the data? As part of GET or POST?

Comment: My friend is making the server side but he wants it to go via http post. I searched but couldn't find anything useful for me (can't really modify the codes myself that good). The idea is that the server will send push notifications via JSON to other devices but that's a later problem. HTTP post is the way  :)

Comment: create web service in php.

Answer (score 0):

Check when return key is pressed you can in `-textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method of `UITextFieldDelegate`. And send post request using `NSURLConnection`.

`.h`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

`.m`:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [self sendData:textField.text];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)sendData:(NSString *)textData
{
    NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://8.8.8.8:80/1.php"]; //the address of your server
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:serverURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [request addValue: @"text/plain charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[textData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *responsedata = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        //..error handler
    }
}
```